# Error trying to find element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, instagram

I'm trying to make an Instagram bot and I need to find and click an element, I already tried using 2 different XPath (which I don´t know why they didn't work) and tried class name (but there are lots of elements with the same class name in this page, and I tried using the [2] method which didn't work), here´s the page source of the element I want to find:

[image]

can someone please help me with how to find and click this element?

Comment: What have you tried so far using code? Post it here.

Answer (score 0):

First find a parent element for the one you're trying to find, then search again for the class name within that element. This way, you can avoid the elements with the same class names.